# In VS 2017 community edition there is no option to install readyroll core

Tags: visual-studio-2017, redgate, readyroll

I have installed SQL 2016 Dev edition and VS 2017 Community edition. Documentation suggests that readyroll core is supported in the community edition. When I look at the VS2017 installer readyroll is missing. Shouldn't I be able to to install it?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK It looks like ReadyRoll core is only available in the Enterprise addition. That's why it doesn't show up as an option.